# SSL para entorno local?

Tags: ssl, localhost

Estoy intentando de instalar un certificado ssl para mi entorno local, me gustaría saber cual es la mejor fuente para instalar uno y cual me recomiendan.

Comment: Bienvenido @marcosRGD.

 Faltan datos para darte una respuesta correcta. Qué servidor usas? Sistema Operativo? Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sin importar el servidor o el sistema operativo, para ambientes locales y respondiendo objetivamente a tu pregunta de

> mejor fuente para instalar uno y cual me recomiendan

**La mejor opción es:** Genera tu propio certificado, ya sea autofirmado ó firmado por una raíz local, y confiarla en el almacén de confianza de tu sistema operativo. Luego usa ese certificado en tu servidor web local.

Cualquiera puede crear su propio certificado sin la ayuda de una AC. La única diferencia es que certificados hechos por ti mismo no van a ser confiados por nadie más. Para desarrollo local, eso está bien. (Puedes googlear para más detalles).

La manera más sencilla para generar una llave privada y un certificado autofirmado para localhost es con el siguiente comando openssl:

```
openssl req -x509 -out localhost.crt -keyout localhost.key \
  -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -sha256 \
  -subj '/CN=localhost' -extensions EXT -config <( \
   printf "[dn]\nCN=localhost\n[req]\ndistinguished_name = dn\n[EXT]\nsubjectAltName=DNS:localhost\nkeyUsage=digitalSignature\nextendedKeyUsage=serverAuth")
```

A continuación, puedes configurar tu servidor con localhost.crt y localhost.key e instalar localhost.crt en tu lista de raices confiadas localmente.

Ya los detalles para instalar openssl puedes buscarlo en google para tu S.O.

Éxitos.

Answer (score 0):

Quisiera retomar este tema.

He creado un tutorial para la comunidad de como hago para crear uno con 'minica'
Pero para lo que lo necesito no funciona, y es para la test de PWA, siguiendo los pasos me sale el candado verde, pero no el boton de "instalar"...

A alguien le ha pasado?